# How to concat multiple text fields in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to concat unique values of some text columns of a pandas dataframe in to a single column.
For example:

```
data = [[1,"US","California","Los Angeles"],
        [1,"US","California","San Francisco"],
        [1,"US","California","San Diego"],
        [1,"US","Texas","Austin"],
        [2,"IND","Maharashtra","Mumbai"],
        [2,"IND","Maharashtra","Pune"],
        [2,"IND","Maharashtra","Nagpur"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country_Id', 'Country','State','Place'])
```

From above dataframe, how do I generate output with one field as `Country_Id` and second with a text field containing the unique values of `Country`, `State`, `Place`.

Like:

- 1,US California Texas Los Angeles San Francisco San Diego Austin
- 2,IND Maharashtra Mumbai Pune Nagpur

Please ignore the meaning of the combined text field

Comment: Check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `apply` with double `join` on `unique` and genexp

```
df.groupby('Country_Id').apply(lambda x: ' '.join(' '.join(x[col].unique()) for col in x))
                        .to_frame('Country-State-Place')


Out[434]:
                                                       Country-State-Place
Country_Id
1           US California Texas Los Angeles San Francisco San Diego Austin
2           IND Maharashtra Mumbai Pune Nagpur
```